# Can't convert frozen model file .pb to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, toco

```
import tensorflow as tf

path = "C:/Users/LAWSSSS/Desktop/convert_pb_2_tflite/frozen_inference_graph-SteelRoll.pb"

inputs = ["image_tensor"]
outputs = ["detection_boxes"]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(path, inputs, outputs, input_shapes={"image_tensor":[1,640,360,3]})
converter.post_training_quantize = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open("frozen_inference_graph-SteelRoll.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I'm new to Tensorflow in general. I tried to use the code above to convert a .pb to .tflite. However, I am getting an error:

```
array.data_type == array.final_data_type Array "image_tensor" has mis-matching actual and final data types (data_type=uint8, final_data_type=float).
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change your model input (the image_tensor placeholder) to have data type tf.float32.